# Get date from line in data file and add to new filename in python

Tags: python

I have a python script that reads and writes a new file after correcting some bad formatting from the logging tool.
Each line in the log file is a new record and I want to be able to extract the data from the first 19 characters of the line data to then append at the end of the new file name.
The start of the line data looks like this `0 20140617191307240` with `0` being the start of a new record and then the following is the date part `20140617191307240` which in datetime format of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmm`
So I want to extract the `yyyy-mm-dd` and then append to the end of the new file name like so

**Current file name**
`4222124650669009.archive`

**After Write**
`4222124650669009.archive.new.2014-06-17`

I am not sure how to go about it correctly, my python script is as follows

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from sys import argv
    import os

    script, filename = argv

    print "Starting Processing"

    newfilename = filename + ".new"

    print "  Old Filename : %r" % filename
    print "  New Filename : %r" % newfilename

    print "  Rebuild Starting"

    source = open(filename, 'r')
    target = open(newfilename, 'w')

    data = False;

    for line in source:
        if line[0:5] == '0 201' and data :
            target.write('\n' + line.strip().replace('\r',' ').replace('\t',' '))
    #       print " " + line[0:132]
        else :
            target.write(line.strip().replace('\r',' ').replace('\t',' '))
    #       print "+" + line[0:132]
        data = True,    

    if data : 
        target.write('\n')

    source.close();
    target.close();


    print "Finished Processing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the date string, in your example `20140617191307240` .
Convert it to the format that you need to add to the new file name.

Then use `os.rename` to rename the file.

```
>>> a = '20140617191307240'
>>> file = '4222124650669009.archive'
>>> to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> new_file_name = file + '.new.' + to_date
>>> new_file_name
'4222124650669009.archive.new.2014-06-17'
>>> os.rename(file,new_file_name)
```